# How to get Selenium tests to run after deployment in visual studio team services

Tags: selenium, testing, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines

I am having an issue getting selenium end to end tests to work after an automated deployment using visual studio team services (VSTS).

I have a build working that generates a build artefact. This is triggered from VSTS but runs on an on premises build server.  I have a deployment working that deploys to an on premises development web server. All this works including unit tests running after the build.

When I try to add testing after the deployment is when I run into the problem. The tests are to be run on the build server and point to the dev server website. The deployment has two phases. A deploy and then an agent phase that runs a test assemblies task using the build agent on the build server. The problem seems to be that the test dll's are not being included in the build artifact and so are never found when the test process runs. Deploy setup us as follows.

[image: Deployment with test assemblies open]

I have a copy files before the publish artifact in the build definition that seems to copy the files in to the right place but they are not included in the zip file artefact. I've looked at several websites and posts on here but I still seem to be missing a vital bit of knowledge that will get this working.

[image: Build def with copy open]

Comment: Could you share the detail build and release log files on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true and add system.debug variable to release definition, then queue build, start release and share log)

Comment: What's the test assembly name? The Copy Files task's content is `*Selenium*.dll`, however Visual Studio Test task's Test Assemblies is `*test*.dll`. On the other hand, what's the BuildConfiguration variable value in Release? (By default, there isn't BuildConfiguration variable)

Comment: The test dll will will be called seleniumtests.dll so would get picked up by both of the search patterns. The reason on is selenium and the other is not is because for the moment I only want to copy those files but may copy others later. all will have the string test in there somewhere The build configuration variable is predefined. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch

Comment: The `BuildConfiguration` variable is user-defined variable instead of predefined, check the its value in release log. On the other hand, could you share build and release log on the OneDrive?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have access to one drive from work. I've added the debug parameters as suggested and looked through the log myself and it did show up a couple of things but nothing conclusive. I am trying a slightly different approach now putting the selenium tests in a separate solution and running it all separately but that is not yet complete and I have to move on to something else for a week or two.

Comment: I guess what would be useful for me would be rather than trying to solve my problem directly perhaps someone could explain the process end to end from their experience of getting something similar to work. I think I may be taking the wrong approach to part of this but I can't seem to find anywhere that does an end to end overview of  how to set it up. I can only find bits that deal with an individual stage and assume you know how to do certain things. As i said I have lots of dev experience but I'm totally new to devops and need help at that level as a result.

Comment: Your workflow is correct, just try to use `**\*test*.dll` in visual studio test task of your Release. The simple way to solve this issue is analysis the build and release log, you can share the log on the OneDrive if it the issue still persist.

Comment: In the screen shot above you are only copying the selenium dll, but not the libraries it depends on, such as the VS test SDK or the selenium packages.

Answer (score -1):

Use of the log did help as recommended so thanks for that.

I have managed to get this working. I separated the selenium tests out into a separate solution and built that separately creating it's own build artefact. I then added this to the agent task in the deploy. This worked. The only thing I need to get sorted now is the correct search path to find the test DLL's. It's not quite as dynamic as I would like at the moment. I can play tunes on that until I get it right though.

I accept this is working around rather than solving the original problem but needs and timescales must. I think moving the end to end UI tests out of the main solution makes sense anyway but no doubt others may think differently.

Thanks for your help everyone